# Scanning for open ports

Tags: c++, security, socket, windows, tcp

I made what started out as a web browser but now is a scanner for open ports. I wanted to know if you think this is a realistic or a unreliable tool for port testing. I found some open ports on my computer and was able to send data through them.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define SCK_VERSION2 0x0202
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 2000
#define DEFAULT_PORT 27015

namespace Globals{
     u_short PORT;
     int i = 135;
}
using namespace Globals;

int sck() {
    //----------------------
    // Declare and initialize variables.
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct sockaddr_in clientService;

    char name[500] = "";
    char ipADDRESS[500] = "";
    char sPORT[500] = "";

    sockaddr_in sName;
    int sNameSize =  sizeof(sName);

    char const* sendbuf = "GET  HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Host: 97-80-226-196.dhcp.leds.al.charter.com\r\n"
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)\r\n"
    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n"
    "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\n"
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\n"
    "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n"
    "Keep-Alive: 300\r\n"
    "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
    "Pragma: no-cache\r\n"
    "DNT: 1"
    "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n\r\n";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;                                    //23.214.132.132 GoDaddy.com
    int WSAERROR = WSAGetLastError();                                   
    //----------------------
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
      printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
      return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %i\n", WSAGetLastError() );
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port of the server to be connected to.

    //u_short PORT;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(//The ip address);                            
    clientService.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    //----------------------
    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService, sizeof(clientService) );
    if ( iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket (ConnectSocket);
        //printf("Unable to connect to server: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());
        int Error = WSAGetLastError();
        cout << i <<": Unable to connect to server: " << Error << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //----------------------
    //Get local host name
    iResult = gethostname(name, sizeof(name));
    if (iResult == NO_ERROR) {
        printf("Host Name: %s\n", name);
    }
    else if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Could not resolve host name: %i", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    //------------------------
    //Get peer name
    iResult = getpeername(ConnectSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&sName, &sNameSize);
    if (iResult == NO_ERROR)
        printf("Peer Name: %s\n", inet_ntoa(sName.sin_addr));
    else if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        printf("Could not get peer name: %i\n", WSAGetLastError());

    //-------------------------
    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else
        printf("Bytes Sent: %i\n", iResult);

    //-----------------------------
    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ( iResult > 0 ) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult); //printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            printf("From server: %s\n", recvbuf);
        }
        else if ( iResult == 0 )
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else if (WSAERROR == WSAETIMEDOUT)
            printf("recv failed: WSAETIMEDOUT\n");
    } while( iResult > 0 );

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int main() {
        for (i;i>=50;i++) {
            PORT = i;
            sck();
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you sending HTTP request to random sockets. Only web servers are expecting HTTP requests. So unless you happen to hit a web server that makes no sense (they generally listen on 80 or 8080). There is not point in trying to hide a web-server.

Answer (score 3):

Servers can keep sockets open indefinitely.

```
// Receive until the peer closes the connection
```

So this will hang your application. Try connecting to port 23 see what happens. Even web-servers can keep the port open longer for chaining (wrong word) requests and not requiring the cost of re-connecting.

#### Global variables!

```
        PORT = i;
        sck();
```

Global variables. What. Don't do it. Functions should be self contained (anything that relies on external state is likely to get something wrong as somebody else changes that state when you least expect it. Pass the port as a parameter.

```
        sck(i);
```

#### Initialization

```
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
```

This only needs to be done once in the application. So you can move this out of the `sck()` function.

#### Don't need to close a connection that was never opened.

```
iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService, sizeof(clientService) );
if ( iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    closesocket (ConnectSocket);  // Its not open at this point.
```

#### Not all error's are errors.

```
iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
```

See [man send](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send): If `send()` returns -1 as an error you need to check `errno` to check the actual error. Not all errors need to be terminal. Eg `EINTR` is not a problem.

#### Don't wait for the server to close the conection.

Answer (score 3):

A few other things to complement Loki's review:

#### Use typed constants instead of macros:

```
static const int SCK_VERSION2   = 0x0202;
static const int DEFAULT_BUFLEN = 2000;
static const int DEFAULT_PORT   = 27015;
```

This has several advantages, such as: having an actual type, respecting scope (when not in the global scope), and producing a debug symbol, so you don't get just a `27015` raw value in the debugger.

I would also suggest not using `ALL_UPPERCASE` anymore after changing to `static const`, since that notation is usually reserved for macro names, but that's up to your preference.

#### `using namespace` defeats the purpose of a namespace:

> ```
> namespace Globals{
>      u_short PORT;
>      int i = 135;
> }
> using namespace Globals;
> ```

The above is just as good as if you had no namespace at all. In your program, you don't really need globals, so just get rid of that an use function parameters. Nevertheless, `using namespace` at a high level scope can be a major source of headaches. I suggest taking the time to [read this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

#### `stdout` is for normal program output:

You're printing errors using `printf` (`stdout`). Program errors should go to the `stderr` stream, to let users filter error output from normal messages. Also, in more strict C++, you should use [`std::cerr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cerr) instead. I also tend to like the readability of format-style printing, but unfortunately, it is an incompatible model with C++, error prone, and violates the Don't Repeat Yourself rule, so I have gradually shifted to the C++ streams over the years for the type safety and type inference. If you don't mid adding the dependency there's also [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/format/).

By the way, there's also one or two `cout`s lost there in the middle. Please be consistent and use one or the other. I'd recommend `std::cout`, for the reasons mentioned above.

#### Pick descriptive names for your functions:

`sck()` tells me nothing, it is just a broken spelling for socket, for a function that does so much...

First, you should break that function into a couple helpers that divide the distinct sub-tasks being performed. Second pick a better name for it, `testPort`, `scanPort` are possible names that come to mind.

#### Careful with excessively noisy comments:

Those `//----------------------` comments cause more distraction than they separate the distinct paragraphs. Most of them also mark the parts that you should instead move to separate functions, so remove those comments and better structure the code instead.